# Ajax, точка в url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Что означает точка в адресе `url` обработчика?

```
                $price_area = $('#price-area');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/prices.reloadprice/",
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType: "text",
```

т.е. что означает часть адреса после точки /prices.**reloadprice**/ ?
выделил жирным

**P.S.**

```
            $price_area = $('#calc-area');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/prices.reloadpricecalc/",
                type:'POST',
                dataType: "text",
```

есть также другой обработчик:  `url: "/prices.reloadpricecalc/",`
т.е. два разных обработчика
`url: "/prices.reloadpricecalc/",`
`url: "/prices.reloadprice/",`

Comment: Ничего не значит. Ulr это просто набор символов. Как его будет понимать сервер это его дело. Конкретно тут, скорее всего это действительно просто имя папки с точкой, но это необязательно.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае /prices.reloadprice/ - это имя папки, т.к. за ней следует слеш, то есть если перевести это на пхп, то будте выполнен следующий файл: /prices.reloadprice/index.php

Но в данном случае точка используется разработчиками для удобного разделение группы запросов и конкретного запроса. Заместо точки может быть любой символ.
То есть не обязательно должен существовать какой-то физический файл /prices.reloadprice/index.php, т.к. может быть настроен редикет данног урла на индексный файл и в результате получится index.php?call=/prices.reloadprice/, где call может быть распарсен и в итоге получим prices и  reloadprice, которые уже можно использовать как угодно в коде.